# Dealing with nested JSON in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm loading a JSON file into PySpark:

```py
df = spark.read.json("20220824211022.json")
df.show()
```

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                data|            includes|                meta|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[{961778216070344...|{[{2018-02-09T01:...|{1562543391161741...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The two columns I'm interested in here are `data` and `includes`. For `data`, I ran the following:

```py
df2 = df.withColumn("data", F.explode(F.col("data"))).select("data.*")
df2.show(2)
```

```
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|          author_id|          created_at|                 id|public_metrics|                text|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 961778216070344705|2022-08-24T20:52:...|1562543391161741312|  {0, 0, 0, 2}|With Kaskada, you...|
|1275784834321768451|2022-08-24T20:47:...|1562542031284555777|  {2, 0, 0, 0}|Below is a protot...|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Which is something I can work with. However I can't do the same with the `includes` column as it has the `{}` enclosing the `[]`.

Is there a way for me to deal with this using PySpark?

EDIT:

If you were to look at the `includes` sections in the JSON file, it looks like:

```json
"includes": {"users": [{"id": "893899303" .... }, ...]},
```

So ideally in the first table in my question, I'd want the `includes` to be `users`, or at least be able to drill down to `users`

Comment: could you use `df3 = df.withColumn("includes", F.explode(F.col("includes").getItem("users"))).select("includes.*")`?

Comment: Thanks! That works. Not quite sure what it is doing though. What the `select("includes.*")` doing with the star?

Comment: It's because after you do the `getItem()`, it returns a struct type. The `select("includes.*")` selects all the column inside this struct. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `includes` column is a `MapType` with `key value = "users"`, you can use the `.getItem()` to get the array by the key, that is:

```
df3 = df.withColumn("includes", F.explode(F.col("includes").getItem("users"))).select("includes.*")
```